# Disable screenshot function in Android and iOS app

Tags: android, ios, screenshot, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm interested in creating an access control app for a project in college. The app would contain a barcode/QR code to read the person identity when placed under a scanner.

To limit unauthorised persons from obtaining access to the barcode used for entry I was hoping to disable a person from taking a screenshot whilst in the app. Is this feature possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, Its not possible .

Answer (score 1):

Dear friend you have to do some tricky thing for this thing as you can't actually prevent user to take screenshot or getting the picture from another mobile,

> so this thing is not gonna solve only by mobile side.
>
> So whats the best approch for this?

According to me you should handle this thing with the help of server side communication store the expiry seconds in QR code data set like:

```
{
  "id" : "some-user-id",
  "ency-key" : "your-latest-key",
  "expiry" : "60"
}
```

here your `ency-key` will be your latest encription key that you will get from server by using webservice or something like that. Now the tricky thing is that this key is only valied for 60 seconds (OR as per your requirement) after getting this key from server, server should refresh the key so if the unauthorized user will try to access the same code by storing in screenshot or photo, he/she will not be able to access the system.

> Thats from my side :) hope this thing may help you

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for iOS:** You `can't` actually prevent user to take screenshot, however you can find if user have just taken screenshot by observing `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` notification and then you can either delete such photo from gallery(if permission have been given) though this is not good at all or you can blur the image. but my point here is, even if you, somehow manage to prevent screenshot, how you gonna prevent user to take photo from other device?

PS. I am not sure if its possible in android or not.